# Can't figure out pointers in C++! Need info about basic strings and pointers

Tags: c++, string, pointers

Hello fellow programmers, my university teacher sent me some solved problems in c++, my friend and I can't figure them out. I will write down the parts that we can't understand.

Problem 1:
You must enter a string, which includes spaces ' ' and the code counts the spaces in the string.
Example:

```
 asd123       count = 0
 a sd123      count = 1
 a s d        count = 2
```

Here is the solution:

```
 typedef char strType[100];
 strType str;
 cout << "string: ";
 cin.getline(str, 100); 
 cout << "\"" << str << "\"\n";


 short count = 0;  
 char *adr = strchr(str, ' '); //value might be NULL

 while (adr)
 {
    ++count;
    adr = strchr(adr + 1, ' ');
 }




cout << "count: " << count << endl;
```

We need explanation after short count =0; We can't understand the value of *adr(is it an exact number, or true or false, or whatever type). How  can you add +1 to adr, how the while cycle ends. Because if the *adr is something complex (consisting of many data) how could you increase it's  value by one(it stores the spaces ' ' occurring in str) and become something which stops the while.

Comment: Read what [strchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/) does. Then look at these two turotials [pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/), [pointer arithmetic](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointer_arithmatic.htm)

Comment: This is mostly C, not C++. Please, point your teacher to this talk: [Stop Teaching C](https://youtu.be/YnWhqhNdYyk). Well, maybe you shouldn't, depending on how receptive she might be...

Comment: He looks kind of stubborn and I am too afraid to confront him directly(since I don't know him very well).

Comment: I'd strongly suggest reading the [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). This might give you an understanding why "stupid" assignments sometimes make sense in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is the first time you've come across pointers. If you don't quite understand them, I'd highly recommend going and learning about them as they are pretty critical to C/C++ (among other languages).

For the benefit of this question, though, I'll give a very rough definition. A pointer "points" to a specific memory location. Its "type" is used to define how much memory it expects to use at that point. That is, a char* pointer will only expect to handle a char's worth of data, and will only reserve that much memory. A long* will reserve and handle a long's worth of memory (significantly larger, how much more depends on the system, but that's another subject).

so when the code snippet you have says:

```
char *adr = strchr(str, ' '); //value might be NULL
```

what is means is: that value of "adr" is a memory location that is the size of type char, which we are setting equal to the result of the library function strchr. We'll get back to strchr in a second.

Now, "str" is what is called a **C-Style string**. This is because it uses the C method for strings, rather than the newer C++  library *string* type, which works slightly differently. A C-Style string is literally a chunk of contiguous (no gaps) memory - in this case, 100 chars all laid out one after another in memory. If I want to read the string, what I do is read each part of it one after another, so I go to the start, read a char, then I want to jump a char's worth of memory forward, to the next char. this is what adr++ does - it says "jump me one step forward", one step in this case being a char, because that is the "type" of adr. That may or may not make sense, Mohamad Elghawi posted a link to a tutorial on pointer arithmetic that's also worth reading.

Back to strchr. strchr is a function that searches for a particular character value within a string. In this case, find me ' ' (space) within str. So it goes to the memory location at the start of str, and jumps through it till if finds a space. If it doesn't find a space, it returns NULL - hence the comment in the code.

If it DOES find a space, it will assign the memory location of that space to adr. Then we jump into the while loop. If adr is **SOMETHING**, then we've found at least one space, so iterate the count. Then we say "ok, the space as adr was the first space, so if there are any more spaces they must be after it, so we do another search for spaces from the memory location *one after adr's current value*, otherwise we would just pick up the same space again and our count would be wrong. Keep doing this until we get NULL as an answer, adding 1 to our count every time adr is not null. when adr is null, there are no more spaces in the string, so our count is finished. Make sense?

Last question you might have: how does strchr know where the end of the string is? Well, this works because C-Style strings are also called "Null-terminated strings" - they automatically have a \0 (Null) value entry at the end. strchr knows that if it hits this value, it has come to the end of the string.

Lesson for next time: pointers are a pretty basic concept that will be covered thoroughly in tutorials and books all over the internet. The chances are that you could have figured out the answer to this in reasonable time had you looked through them, and looked up what strchr does. However, we were all beginners once and I realise that it's often a bit daunting. Try a little harder to find an existing answer first next time :)

Answer (score 0):

In your example [strchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/?kw=strchr) returns the  character pointer pointing to the location which has value space in string. If it is a valid pointer while loop allow it to enter loop and increment the value of variable count. add+1 is the pointer arithmetic to reach the next character pointer in location in string after the space character in string.